# Is it common practice to omit some points in an airway?

Tags: flight-planning, airways

An airline filed the following flight plan:

> [...] IRK.J96.SLN..LANCY.J134.PKE [...]

The cruise altitude was around 30k feet.

Waypoints in J96 are:

```
LAX PDZ YCDIL PKE* LANCY* DRK KEYKE GUP CIM GCK SLN* AGENT KIDER IRK* NORIS PIA JOT
```

J96 spans between 18k-45k feet.

So it means that someone put a direct in the middle of an airway. Why was the flight plan not filed with an all-airway routing like this:

> [...] IRK.J96.LANCY.J134.PKE [...]

Is it common practice to omit some points in an airway?

Comment: Guessing only, but maybe the direct is frequently approved and thus planning on it better reflects what will happen? It’s only a couple of miles, though...

Comment: It's 967 miles and as far as I saw it's not that common to fly direct

Comment: I meant the shortcut is only a few miles shorter than following the airway... and hey, all I gave was a random possibility. Without speaking to the original planner, chances are we’re not going to find out the rationale behind the plan, anyway (or whether it was simply a typo or other glitch, for that matter).

Comment: Objection your Honor, the question calls for speculation...

Comment: Indeed we would have to speak with the original planner. I am new to industry, so I thought maybe it's a common practice to omit some points in the airway. If it's not then it's also valuable knowledge :).